# How do I use jQuery to change the CSS of direct img sibling elements matching a class conditional

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to make a set of greyed out images switch with color images when a checkbox is checked within a table row. This operation will be reversed when the checkbox is unchecked again. The changes must only apply to img elements in that particular tablerow. The table rows will be dynamically generated but will follow this DOM structure. I have looked into .parent() .parentAll() but these do not seem to provide the matches. I am happy to apply non jQuery javascript if it is not possible in jQuery but I would prefer to use jQuery if possible

```
<html>

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title> Total Tutor </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="course.css"> 
          <script src="../jquery.js"></script> 

    <style>
       .color{display:none;}
       .grey{display:block;}  
    </style>

  </head>   

 <body>

  <div>  
   <form>
    <table id="units" >

     <thead> 
       <tr>
        <th>Units</th> 
            <th>Add Video</th>
            <th>Add Worksheet</th>
            <th>Add Quiz</th>
            <th>Add Exam</th>
            <th>Add Revision</th>
        </tr>  
      </thead>

      <tbody>

       <!--  table rows will be dynamically generated based on a SQL query -->
        <tr>
            <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 2.1.1.1</td>
            <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>      
            <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>    
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 3.1.1.1</td>
            <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>      
            <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>    
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table> 

    <button type="submit" id="save_design_course" name="sent" value="save_design_course"><img src="../images/save.png"></button>

  </form>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>  

<script>

  $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $(".design_units").click(function ()
      {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display: none 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:block*/
        } 

       if (!$(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display:block 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:none*/
        } 
      });    
</script>
```

Comment: you can use change event also no need for another if statement use else after the first if it means not checked

Comment: I have already done that bit by using click!

Comment: you have lot of syntax errors in the code. document.ready is not closed

Comment: As an aside, `if (this.checked)` is easier to read, faster to type, and faster to execute than `if ($(this).is(':checked'))`.

Comment: does that not target the DOM element rather than the jQuery object though?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have lot of syntax errors in the script block.

You can use closest() and find tr and access the color and grey classes

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $(".design_units").on('click',function(){
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display: none 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:block*/
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.color').show();
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.grey').hide();          
        } 

       if (!$(this).is(':checked')){
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display:block 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:none*/
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.color').hide();
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.grey').show();
        } 
      });  
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. If it is gonna generate dynamically use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as

`$("body").on("change", ".design_units", function(){
     //Your code
});`

You can use other selector instead of "body", if that is present on page while event binding.

2. Use [find](http://api.jquery.com/find/) and [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to find the exact elements in your case.
   for eg. -

   `$(this).closest('tr').find('.grey').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

another simple way to show and hide your image, is using `toggle()` rather than checking its `checked` property

`toggle()` is used to switch the visibility of elements from `hide` to `show`, vice versa.

```
$(".design_units").click(function ()
{
  $(this).parents('tr').find('img.grey').toggle();
  $(this).parents('tr').find('img.color').toggle();
});
```

demo : https://jsfiddle.net/81sLL212/

Answer (score 1):

Within the `click` handler (or you could use a `change` handler, but either is OK for checkboxes) you can find the clicked element's associated images by using [`.closest("tr")`](http://api.jquery.com/closest) to navigate up to the containing row, then [`.find("img")`](http://api.jquery.com/find) to navigate back down to the images in that row.

Then you can call [`.toggle()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) on those images, [passing a boolean argument](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/#toggle-display) to indicate whether to show or hide each one.

This means you don't need an `if/else` structure and the event handler can be reduced to three lines:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".design_units").click(function() {            // When a CB is clicked
    var imgs = $(this).closest("tr").find("img");  // find its associated imgs
    imgs.filter(".color").toggle(this.checked);    // Show color if CB checked
    imgs.filter(".grey").toggle(!this.checked);    // Show grey if CB not checked
  });
});
```

```css
.color { display: none; }
.grey { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <table id="units">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 2.1.1.1</td>
          <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" alt="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" alt="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>
          <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" alt="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" alt="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 3.1.1.1</td>
          <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" alt="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" alt="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>
          <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" alt="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" alt="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
```

Note that when dealing with a single checkbox `this.checked` gives you the same boolean value as `$(this).is(':checked')`, except it is easier to read, faster to type, and faster to execute.

(Note: in the demo above I've given the  images an `alt` attribute so that you can tell whether they're the `.color` or `.grey` ones without needing valid `src` paths.)

**EDIT:** If the table is dynamically generated in the sense of being loaded via Ajax *after* the initial page load then replace the following line:

```
$(".design_units").click(function() {
```

...with:

```
$(document).on("click", ".design_units", function() {
```

Where ideally `document` would be replaced by the nearest parent element that is static.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `closest()` to get the nearest ancestor with a particular tag, then `find()` to get all children matching a jQuery selector under that ancestor.

I switched the images for buttons because we don't have access to the actual images, and closed the `document.ready()` function:

```js
  $(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $(".design_units").click(function ()
      {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.grey').hide();
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.color').show();
        } 

       if (!$(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.grey').show();
          $(this).closest('tr').find('.color').hide();
        } 
      });
   });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

  <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title> Total Tutor </title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="course.css"> 
          <script src="../jquery.js"></script> 

    <style>
       .color{display:none;}
       .grey{display:block;}  
    </style>

  </head>   

 <body>

  <div>  
   <form>
    <table id="units" >

     <thead> 
       <tr>
        <th>Units</th> 
            <th>Add Video</th>
            <th>Add Worksheet</th>
            <th>Add Quiz</th>
            <th>Add Exam</th>
            <th>Add Revision</th>
        </tr>  
      </thead>

      <tbody>

       <!--  table rows will be dynamically generated based on a SQL query -->
        <tr>
            <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 2.1.1.1</td>
            <td class="unit_table"><button class="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><button class="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>      
            <td class="unit_table"><button class="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><button class="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>    
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 3.1.1.1</td>
            <td class="unit_table"><button class="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><button class="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>      
            <td class="unit_table"><button class="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><button class="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>    
        </tr>

      </tbody>
    </table> 

    <button type="submit" id="save_design_course" name="sent" value="save_design_course"><img src="../images/save.png"></button>

  </form>
 </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You might use the `.parents()` selector to get the appropriate table row, then search for the image you want within that row. Here's an example solution to your problem following that pattern:

```
$('.design-units').on('change', (e)=>{
  const $row = $(e.target).parents('tr');
  const $grays = $row.find('.grey');
  const $colors = $row.find('.color');

  const isChecked = $(e.target).is(':checked');

  if(isChecked){
    $grays.attr('disabled', false);
    $colors.attr('disabled', true);
  } else {
    $grays.attr('disabled', true);
    $colors.attr('disabled', false);
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to iterate through each `img` as

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    {
     $(".design_units").click(function ()
      {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
         $(this).parent().nextAll('td').find('img').each(function(){
          if($(this).attr('class') == 'color')
          {
            $(this).css('display','block');
          }else if($(this).attr('class') == 'grey')
          {
            $(this).css('display','none');
          }
         })
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display: none 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:block*/
        } 

       if (!$(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
        $(this).parent().nextAll('td').find('img').each(function(){
          if($(this).attr('class') == 'grey')
          {
            $(this).css('display','block');
          }else if($(this).attr('class') == 'color')
          {
            $(this).css('display','none');
          }
         })
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display:block 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:none*/
        } 
      });   
      });
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/gaq23jbL/3/

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
    <html>
    <hrad></head>
    <body>
    <div>  
           <form>
            <table id="units" >

             <thead> 
               <tr>
                <th>Units</th> 
                    <th>Add Video</th>
                    <th>Add Worksheet</th>
                    <th>Add Quiz</th>
                    <th>Add Exam</th>
                    <th>Add Revision</th>
                </tr>  
              </thead>

              <tbody>

               <!--  table rows will be dynamically generated based on a SQL query -->
                <tr>
                    <td class="unit_table"><input type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 2.1.1.1</td>
                    <td class="unit_table"><img alt="color" class="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><img alt="grey" class="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>      
                    <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>    
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td class="unit_table"><input  type="checkbox" class="design_units" name="units[]" value="Bike"> Unit 3.1.1.1</td>
                    <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/video-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/video-selector-small-grey.png"></td>      
                    <td class="unit_table"><img class="color" src="../images/worksheet-selector-small.png"><img class="grey" disabled src="../images/worksheet-selector-small-grey.png"></td>    
                </tr>

              </tbody>
            </table> 

            <button type="submit" id="save_design_course" name="sent" value="save_design_course"><img src="../images/save.png"></button>

          </form>
         </div>


        <script>
            $(function(){
          $('#units').on('click','.design_units',function ()
      {
       if ($(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
            $($(this).closest('tr').find('.grey')).hide();
          $($(this).closest('tr').find('.color')).show();
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display: none 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:block*/
        } 

       if (!$(this).is(':checked')) 
        {
        $($(this).closest('tr').find('.grey')).show();
          $($(this).closest('tr').find('.color')).hide();
          /*change all of the img elements of class grey to display:block 
          and change all img elements of class color to display:none*/
        } 
 });
        });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

[js-fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vikastiwari42422/j4859ts4/21/)